want to a trigger a function when we click on the specific key?
we will trigger a function based on the charcode values of the keys.
Here is the example to get the the charcode values of the keys
window:keypress  is an javascript event.this event was trigerred all over the window
<div>
<p (window:keypress)="getcharcodeValue($event)">Click me!</p>
</div>
<p*ngIf="show">show me</p>

for Example, we want to trigger the getcharcodeValue() function for the key Enter.the keycode for Enter is 13.now all over the window when we press the enter key the function will trigger
intially set the value oof show is true
triggerFunction(){
this.show = true
}
getcharcodeValue(event:any){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
      triggerFunction()
}


Check this two links: https://netbasal.com/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-your-angular-app-9bf2e89862b3 and https://netbasal.com/diy-keyboard-shortcuts-in-your-angular-application-4704734547a2. In brief, you can use renderer, hostListener and binding to a event. There're another way taht it's use fromEvent rxjs operator

you can set events for keydown/keyup on a specific elements (ex: (keydown.Enter)="showMe()" ) but to get keyboard input it needs to be able to take those events (like an ...) For document-wide the answer below is your best bet.  Also see here for a list of names you can use after "keydown." or "keyup.": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_code_values  (not case sensitive)

You are looking for host listener, we can directly specify the event we need and just toggle the flag
Full code
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Click me!</p>
    </div>
    <p *ngIf="show">show this</p>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  show = false;

  @HostListener('document:keydown.enter', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(
    event: KeyboardEvent
  ) {
    this.show = true;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
